# tinyMCE when on fullscreen mode show HTML CODE by default

Tags: javascript, html, api, editor, tinymce

when i click Fullscreen button on tinyMCE, it opens in new window.

All i want now is in this new window which has the tinyMCE in full screen, to be in HTML Source code mode by default.

Also, i want the window of "html code editing" to be in full screen.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to follow this [fiddle](http://fiddle.tinymce.com/K8caab) for  showing HTML code by default

```
In order to implement it in FullScreen Plugin go to 
plugins/fullscreen/fullscreen.htm
```

Open fullscreen.htm and add onload event to the body like

```
onload="setTimeout(tinyMCE.activeEditor.execCommand('mceCodeEditor'),200)"
```

For "html code editing" to be in full screen

```
Go to themes/advanced/editor_template.js
```

locate

```
width : parseInt(ed.getParam("theme_advanced_source_editor_width", 720)),
height : parseInt(ed.getParam("theme_advanced_source_editor_height", 580)),

replace 720 and 580 by screen.availWidth, screen.availHeight respectively.

Also clear your browser cache.
```

Hope it helps!!

Comment: This is an excellent answer i guess but i want to implement it in Fullscreen plugin! Do you know how to do it there?

Comment: Thank you very much! Your answer is correct! What about the second part of my question? "Also, i want the window of "html code editing" to be in full screen."

Answer (score 0):

The fullscreen button will enlarge the tinymce editor to the users fullscreen size. Showing the source code is another operation like you found out yourself already - the html code editing.

To get that in full screen size you will have to adjust the popup size of tinymce html source editor. This can be done using the following tinymce configuration parameter

- [theme_advanced_source_editor_height](http://www.tinymce.com/wiki.php/Configuration%3atheme_advanced_source_editor_height)
- [theme_advanced_source_editor_width](http://www.tinymce.com/wiki.php/Configuration%3atheme_advanced_source_editor_width)

Unfortunately, you will be able to define a fixed width and heigth only. There is no option to enlarge the code popup window to fullscreen size.

Comment: you cannot see the source code by default in the editor (tinymce is a wysiwyg rte) - so you get what you see. the html code view is located somewhere else (the function and popup you get clicking the "html"-button)

Comment: And how can i call this function on page load without clicking the "html" button?

Comment: I'm pretty sure that if someone could tell me how can i call on page load the function of "html" button and right afterwards call the function of maximize window of "html source editor", i will achieve all i want to do!